# Laravel 4: Workbench Blade @include

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have blade files in the views folder on Workbench. I tried to do `@include`, but it is looking for the file inside views folder on my workbench. How can I get @include to include file on `app/views` folder, not `workbench/myvendor/mypackage/src/views`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to publish your workbench views to the app to make them accessible.

```
php artisan view:publish vendor/package
```

the `Views` would then be included with:

```
@include('packages/vendor/package/viewname')
```

http://laravel.com/docs/packages#package-views gives more info

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Regarding `view:publish`, as I am working in workbench directory, so I tried with `view:publish --bench="MyVendor/MyPackage"`. But it return with the error `The "--bench" option does not exist.` So, how can I get it works?